How to setup npm registry during a Docker build in a gitlab CI
I'm trying to deploy a Next.js app that imports a design system. This design system is published on a private NPM registry.
I have two related jobs in my CI: init and deploy
Init is fairly simple:
# Default values used in all jobs
default:
  image: ${CI_DEPENDENCY_PROXY_GROUP_IMAGE_PREFIX}/node:20-alpine
  interruptible: true
  cache: # Cache modules using lock file
    key:
      files:
        - package-lock.json
    paths:
      - .npm/
  before_script:
    - echo "@${CI_PROJECT_ROOT_NAMESPACE}:registry=${CI_API_V4_URL}/packages/npm/" > .npmrc
    - echo "//${CI_SERVER_HOST}/:_authToken=${GITLAB_GROUP_DEPLOY_TOKEN}" >> .npmrc
    # Ignore the scripts to avoid `npm prepare` from being executed
    - npm ci --cache .npm --prefer-offline --ignore-scripts

# Init
init:
  stage: .pre # this job will be run before all others
  script:
    - echo "Caching all assets for subsequent jobs."

It works fine: the .npmrc is properly created. But it always fail during the deploy job.
here is what I tried so far:

Deploying with hard-coded values stored in a .npmrc. It works fine, but obviously, we do not want this.
Adding the same echo commands,  but it doesn't work: logging its content reveals that the environment variables don't exist:

    #14 0.398 @:registry=/packages/npm/
    #14 0.398 ///:_authToken=


Adding a .npmrc in my app, with concatenated values, with the same result
Adding the ARG and ENV values directly in my Dockerfile. It works, but I assume this is not a secure way to do so.

It appears that the CI variables and the deploy token are not properly passed down from the CI to the Dockerfile.

Please check answers to this question.
